# Rails Non RESTful dilemma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a very simple model "Coupon". I suddenly am interested to add two more fields, "redeem_code" and "redeemed" to the model for obvious reasons.

I would like to make a view for a merchant to redeem a coupon based on a code.

The simplest approach that I can think of to just do this would be something like this:

```
  def redeem
    #renders the page
  end

  def redeem_post
    redeem_code = params[:redeem_code]
    deal = Deal.find_by_redeem_code(redeem_code)

    if deal.nil? 
      # BUG: Somehow here you will be logged out 
      redirect_to deals_path
    else 
      if deal.update_attribute(:redeemed, true)
        redirect_to deals_path
      end
    end
  end
```

As far as I am concerned, rails doesn't really support non restful interfaces. I tried digging up form helpers last night but I was not able to find anything so I just put togehter something real fast:

```
<form action="<%= deals_redeem_post_path %>" method="post">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th> Code: </th>
      <td> <input type="text" name="redeem_code" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td> <input type="submit" text="Submit" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```

I am using devise. The bug that I am experiencing right now is when my user submits this form, he/she will be automatically logged out.

Any ideas how I can fix this or implement this more elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing the authenticity token (which prevents [Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf)) which is automatically generated.  You want to use the form for helper for that generates this automatically.

```
<%= form_for(:coupon, :url => deals_redeem_post_path) do |f| %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: Yeah thx! I didn't kow you can use form_for without a class variable